# How to place radio buttons next to labels

Tags: html, css

I have started learning basics of web dev and currently I'm trying out html and css. My questions is how to make radio buttons to appear on the right side of labels (question) like it is on the left side of the picture. Right now all I can do is that on the right. Could you help me please?

[image]

here is my css:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500);
body {
  background-color: #a9d7d1;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 320px;
}

#title {
  text-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  width: 60%;
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

#description {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#name-label,
#email-label,
#age-label,
#Role-label,
#userRating-label,
#most-like-label,
#preferences-label #comments-label {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#submit {
  color: white;
  background-color: #59ace0;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

textarea {
  width: 30%;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 35px;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#name,
#email,
#age {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="preferences-div">

  <label for="preferences" name="preferences" id="preferences-label">Things that should be improved in the future<br>(Check all that apply):</label>

  <ul id="preferences" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Front-end Projects</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="2" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Back-end Projects</li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="3" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Data Visualization</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="4" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Challenges</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="5" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Open Source Community</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="6" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Gitter help rooms</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="7" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Videos</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="8" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">City Meetups</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="9" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Wiki</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Forum</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Additional Courses</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: here is my css:

Comment: i added now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution:

```css
#preferences {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

#preferences-label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="preferences-div">

    <label for="preferences" name="preferences" id="preferences-label">Things that should be improved in the future<br>(Check all that apply):</label>

    <ul id="preferences">
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Front-end Projects</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="2" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Back-end Projects</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="3" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Data Visualization</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="4" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Challenges</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="5" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Open Source Community</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="6" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Gitter help rooms</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="7" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Videos</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="8" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">City Meetups</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="9" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Wiki</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Forum</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Additional Courses</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="preferences-div">

    <label for="preferences" name="preferences" id="preferences-label">Things that should be improved in the future<br>(Check all that apply):</label>

    <ul id="preferences" style="list-style: none;">
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Front-end Projects</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="2" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Back-end Projects</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="3" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Data Visualization</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="4" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Challenges</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="5" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Open Source Community</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="6" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Gitter help rooms</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="7" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Videos</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="8" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">City Meetups</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="9" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Wiki</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Forum</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Additional Courses</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Just take the label tag out, like this:

```html
<div id="preferences-div">

    <label for="preferences" name="preferences" id="preferences-label">Things that should be improved in the future<br>(Check all that apply):</label>

    <ul id="preferences" style="list-style: none;">
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Front-end Projects</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="2" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Back-end Projects</li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="3" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Data Visualization</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="4" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Challenges</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="5" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Open Source Community</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="6" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Gitter help rooms</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="7" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Videos</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="8" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">City Meetups</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="9" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Wiki</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Forum</label></li>
      <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Additional Courses</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```html
<div id="preferences-div">

    <label for="preferences" name="preferences" id="preferences-label">Things that should be improved in the future<br>(Check all that apply):</label>

    <ul id="preferences" style="list-style: none;">
      <li class="checkbox">Front-end Projects<input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #a9d7d1;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 320px;
}

#title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  width: 60%;
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

#description {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#preferences-label {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#submit {
  color: white;
  background-color: #59ace0;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}

textarea {
  width: 30%;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 35px;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

#preferences-div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="preferences-div">

  <label for="preferences" name="preferences" id="preferences-label">Things that should be improved in the future<br>(Check all that apply):</label>

  <ul id="preferences" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="1" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Front-end Projects</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><input name="prefer" value="2" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Back-end Projects</li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="3" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Data Visualization</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="4" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Challenges</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="5" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Open Source Community</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="6" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Gitter help rooms</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="7" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Videos</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="8" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">City Meetups</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="9" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Wiki</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Forum</label></li>
    <li class="checkbox"><label><input name="prefer" value="10" type="checkbox" class="userRatings">Additional Courses</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```